# Enum, how to display multiple word in simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, simple-form

I'm using enum for `:discount_type`. The enum is either `percent` or `price`.

For clarity purposes I would like to show `price per day` in my simple_form for the enum `price`. How can I do this?

**Code**

model

```
enum discount_type: { percent: 1, price: 0 }
```

form

```
<%= f.input :discount_type, collection: ['percent', 'price'] %>
```

**previous attempt**

```
model
enum discount_type: { percent: 1, price_per_day: 0 }

form
<%= f.input :discount_type, collection: ['percent', 'price per day'] %>

error message:
==> 'price per day' is not a valid discount_type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> The mappings are exposed through a class method with the pluralized
>   attribute name, which returns the mapping in a
>   HashWithIndifferentAccess...

This is a bit ugly, because of the `per day` addition to `price`:

```
Model.discount_types.transform_keys { |key| key == 'price' ? 'price per day' : key }.keys
# ["percent", "price per day"]
```

So, in your form:

```
<%= f.input :discount_type, collection: Model.discount_types.transform_keys { |key| key == 'price' ? 'price per day' : key }.keys %>
```